# Import Error with @react-three/drei / react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, react-three-fiber, drei

I'm trying to use **[@react-three/drei](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei)**. I've successfully installed and used **[@react-three/fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber)** but when I installed `@react-three/drei`. I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/three-stdlib/lights/RectAreaLightUniformsLib.js
Attempted import error: 'DataUtils' is not exported from 'three'.
```

*Getting the error when I use this import for @react-three/drei-*

```
import { Preload, ScrollControls, Scroll, useScroll, Image, useFBO, PerspectiveCamera } from '@react-three/drei'
```

**App.jsx**

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { Suspense, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Preload, ScrollControls, Scroll, useScroll, Image, useFBO, PerspectiveCamera } from '@react-three/drei'

import SiteNav from "./components/Nav/Nav"
import MainContainer from "./pages/MainContainer";

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <SiteNav />
        <MainContainer />
      </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is react-three/drei uses stand alone three-stdlib `npm i three-stdlib` should solve the problem.

https://github.com/pmndrs/drei  react-drei docs says the following:

> A growing collection of useful helpers and abstractions for react-three-fiber.
>
> npm install @react-three/drei  this package is using the stand-alone
> three-stdlib instead of  three/examples/jsm.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by running the command

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps three
```